# loginInfo always null when logging in via UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, identityserver3

I try to extend the standard MVC Auth example (http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on) with OpenID Connect authentication to an instance of the Thinktecture IdentityServer (https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/Simplest%20OAuth2%20Walkthrough).

I added the 'openid' scope to the Scopes of the IdentityServer.
I used the example code in https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/blob/master/source/MVC%20Authentication/EmbeddedMvc/Startup.cs to add the extra call to the userinfo endpoint.

Higher up in the authentication middleware chain are - as per the MVC Auth example - `UseCookieAuthentication` and `UseExternalSignInCookie`.

When I put a breakpoint in the `OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications.SecurityTokenValidated`, I can see that all the claims are nicely coming in. So the communication with the IdentityServer is correct.

But when I reach `AccountController.ExternalLoginCallback` the call to

```
var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
```

always returns null.

It is not null when I login with Google OAuth2.

I suspect a mismatch between how the `UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication` sets (or does not set) Cookie information, and the way `UseCookieAuthentication` extracts it. But I am clueless how to resolve this.

Answer (score 3):

It turned out that the example code in https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/blob/master/source/MVC%20Authentication/EmbeddedMvc/Startup.cs did overwrite the claim with type

```
"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier".
```

If this claim is not found, loginInfo is not found.

Problem code (Startup.Auth.cs):

```
var nid = new ClaimsIdentity(
    n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AuthenticationType,
    Constants.ClaimTypes.GivenName, // "given_name"
    Constants.ClaimTypes.Role // "role"
);
```

Solution was to keep the original claims, like this:

```
var nid = new ClaimsIdentity(
    n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity, 
    n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.Claims
);
```

Comment: In my case, the solution wasn't to keep the original claims, but to ensure that the reissued ticket always contained a NameIdentifier claim.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and though I didn't come up with the reason why you could sometimes authenticate and bring back an identity's claims I did manage to work out why the ExternalLoginInfo was always null by downloading and debugging the Microsoft code.

The problem for me was with the **ResponseType** supplied in the OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions - I had it set to **OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code** which was incorrect... setting it to **OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken** got it working consistently.

Here's a copy of my Startup.Auth.vb source:

```
Public Sub ConfigureAuth(app As IAppBuilder)
    app.CreatePerOwinContext(AddressOf ApplicationDbContext.Create)
    app.CreatePerOwinContext(Of ApplicationUserManager)(AddressOf ApplicationUserManager.Create)
    app.CreatePerOwinContext(Of ApplicationSignInManager)(AddressOf ApplicationSignInManager.Create)
   app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType)
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(New CookieAuthenticationOptions() With {
        .AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        .Provider = New CookieAuthenticationProvider() With {
            .OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity(Of ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser)(
                validateInterval:=TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                regenerateIdentity:=Function(manager, user) user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))},
        .LoginPath = New PathString("/Account/Login")})
    app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie)

    Dim facebookOptions = New FacebookAuthenticationOptions With {
        .AppId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("FacebookClientID"),
        .AppSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("FacebookClientSecret"),
        .Provider = New FacebookAuthenticationProvider With {
            .OnAuthenticated = Function(context)
                                   context.Identity.AddClaim(New Claim("Provider", "Facebook"))
                                   context.Identity.AddClaim(New Claim("provider:name", context.Identity.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Name)))
                                   context.Identity.AddClaim(New Claim("provider:accesstoken", context.AccessToken, ClaimValueTypes.String, "Facebook"))
                                   context.Identity.AddClaim(New Claim("provider:picture", String.Format("//graph.facebook.com/{0}/picture?type=square", context.User.Value(Of String)("id"))))
                                   Dim email = context.Identity.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email)
                                   If email IsNot Nothing Then
                                       context.Identity.AddClaim(New Claim("provider:email", email))
                                   Else
                                       Dim fb = New Facebook.FacebookClient(context.AccessToken)
                                       Dim myInfo = fb.Get("/me?fields=email")
                                       email = myInfo("email")
                                       If email IsNot Nothing Then
                                           context.Identity.AddClaim(New Claim("provider:email", email))
                                       Else
                                           Throw New ArgumentNullException("myInfo.Email")
                                       End If
                                   End If

                                   Return Task.FromResult(0)
                               End Function}}
    facebookOptions.Scope.Add("email")
    app.UseFacebookAuthentication(facebookOptions)

    app.UseGoogleAuthentication(New GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions() With {
       .ClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("GoogleClientID"),
       .ClientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("GoogleClientSecret"),
       .Provider = New GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationProvider With {.OnAuthenticated = Function(context)
                                                                                       context.Identity.AddClaim(New Claim("Provider", "Google"))
                                                                                       context.Identity.AddClaim(New Claim("provider:name", context.Identity.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Name)))
                                                                                       context.Identity.AddClaim(New Claim("provider:email", context.Identity.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email)))
                                                                                       context.Identity.AddClaim(New Claim("provider:accesstoken", context.AccessToken, ClaimValueTypes.String, "Google"))
                                                                                       context.Identity.AddClaim(New Claim("provider:picture", context.User.SelectToken("image")?.Value(Of String)("url")))

                                                                                       Return Task.FromResult(0)
                                                                                   End Function}})

    app.UseLinkedInAuthentication(New LinkedInAuthenticationOptions With {
        .ClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("LinkedInClientID"),
        .ClientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("LinkedInClientSecret"),
        .Provider = New LinkedInAuthenticationProvider With {.OnAuthenticated = Function(context)
                                                                                    context.Identity.AddClaim(New Claim("Provider", "LinkedIn"))
                                                                                    context.Identity.AddClaim(New Claim("provider:name", context.Name))
                                                                                    context.Identity.AddClaim(New Claim("provider:email", context.Email))
                                                                                    context.Identity.AddClaim(New Claim("provider:accesstoken", context.AccessToken, ClaimValueTypes.String, "LinkedIn"))
                                                                                    context.Identity.AddClaim(New Claim("provider:picture", context.User.SelectToken("pictureUrl").ToString))

                                                                                    Return Task.FromResult(0)
                                                                                End Function}})

    Dim oktaOptions = New OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions With {
        .AuthenticationType = "okta",
        .SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",
        .Authority = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("okta:Authority"),
        .ResponseType = Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken,
        .ClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("okta:ClientId"),
        .ClientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("okta:ClientSecret"),
        .RedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("okta:RedirectUri"),
        .TokenValidationParameters = New Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters With {.ValidateIssuer = True},
        .Scope = "openid profile email"
    }
    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(oktaOptions)


    Dim auth0Options = New OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions With {
        .AuthenticationType = "auth0",
        .SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",
        .Authority = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("auth0:Authority"),
        .ResponseType = Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken,
        .ClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("auth0:ClientId"),
        .ClientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("auth0:ClientSecret"),
        .RedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("auth0:RedirectUri"),
        .TokenValidationParameters = New Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters With {.ValidateIssuer = True},
        .Scope = "openid profile email"
    }
    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(auth0Options)

    app.MapSignalR

    GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Register(GetType(IUserIdProvider), Function() New MySignalRIdProvider())
End Sub
```